# Programmatically download from app store

Tags: ios, http, download, wireshark, packet

**Is it possible to download an app from Apple app store programmatically without using iTunes?**

I have tried *Wireshark* to catch packets while downloading an app in iTunes from my iPhone. In the trace, I've got a HTTP packet which revealed the URL of the app I downloaded.

That is: http://a558.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Purple/v4/d1/8f/93/d18f931b-f90c-6830-236f-1be569e3c9ee/mzps4099439710744129538.D2.dpkg.ipa

However, when I used Wget to download from this URL, it turned out to be `403 Forbidden`.

The reason why I asked for help is that there are some "smart routers" which claimed to accelerate downloading from the app store, and I want to download some apps to test the real downloading speed and verify it. However, I do not want to click every download from the iTunes. I have my own Apple account and I will only download free apps.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I suspect that not many here are going to help you unless you can explain your intentions clearly, as there's a lot of possibility for abuse/misuse here.

Comment: Thank you! There are some "smart routers" which claimed to accelerate downloading from the app store. I want to download some apps to test the real downloading speed (with the "accelerating function" on and off) and verify that function, however, I do not  want to click every download from the iTunes. That is why I asked for help. I have my own Apple account and I will only download free apps. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you find an answer? I asked the same question on AskDifferent and was suggested AppleScript, but it doesn't seem like iTunes has enough API depth to support the required operations. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130563/automatic-download-of-top-apps-from-itunes-app-store-in-itunes I do assume that you need to sign your requests that you do to Apple's server. It's probably going to take some deep (?) hacking skills to pull that off. If the requests are going to http:// rather than https:// then there might be a chance that the request contents are sent in plain text.

Comment: By the way, I am trying to download apps on a computer (OS X) using the iTunes software (or without it if possible); not on an iOS device.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget other headers like 'user-agent' and cookie:

wget --header='User-Agent: iTunes/12.1.1 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Business Edition Service Pack 1 (Build 7601); x64) AppleWebKit/7600.1017.9000.2' --header='Accept: */*' --header='Cookie: downloadKey=expires=1426914268~access=/us/r1000/131/Purple3/v4/f8/f8/c5/f8f8c50a-90fc-f62f-af89-796bf89111c6/gbp3951770696681909972.D2.pd.ipa*~md5=11e28a91dbf5454de97148d90fce5386' 'http://a1834.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/131/Purple3/v4/f8/f8/c5/f8f8c50a-90fc-f62f-af89-796bf89111c6/gbp3951770696681909972.D2.pd.ipa'